# Menu list - background-color of the text area doesn't change on hover

Tags: css, list, menu, background, hover

I've a problem with my list menu.

The `background-color` change on hover, but just on `the box` area, the `text-area` background doesn't change.

I like to find a way how to achieve this:

here is my code:

```
<div class="services">
                <ul>
                    <li class="general"><a href="" title="" >General</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="" >Marketing and Brand Strategy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="" >Events and Launches at Exhibitions</a></li>    
                        <li><a href="" title="" >PR / Press releases,</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="" >Distribution and sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="" >Media and social media</a></li?
                </ul>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.services ul { display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    .services ul li{ list-style-type: none; background: #ffffff; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; width:350px  }
    .services ul li:hover{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; }
    .services ul ul:hover >a{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt;  }
    .services ul li a{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none;background-color:#ffffff }
    .services ul li a:hover{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none;background-color:#efefef; }
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/r8rns8gw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `background-color:#ffffff;` to `.services ul li a` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8rns8gw/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.services ul { display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    .services ul li{ list-style-type: none; background: #ffffff; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; width:350px  }
    .services ul li:hover{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; }
    .services ul ul:hover >a{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt;  }
    .services ul li a{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none; }
    .services ul li a:hover{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none;background-color:#efefef; }
```

Comment: Sorry, jsut one thing, If i wan to let the backgroudn colro grey when it's selected, how do i manage this ?

Comment: @user3439889 OK.. and what do you mean by that you want the background color to gray, when it's selected???

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background-color property for the  tag. I mean remove it from the last two lines of your css. It will work.

```
    .services ul { display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    .services ul li{ list-style-type: none; background: #ffffff; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; width:350px  }
    .services ul li:hover{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt; }
    .services ul ul:hover >a{ list-style-type: none; background: #efefef; line-height: 47px; border-top: 1px solid white; font-size: 12pt;  }
    .services ul li a{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none;}
    .services ul li a:hover{ width:100%; color: black; padding: 0 12px; font-family: 'Lora', serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none; }
```